# I need to include the table_schema, table_name and column_name in my query output with values

Tags: mysql, union, information-schema, tablename, amazon-athena

I am creating a report to identify the maximum batch_id for each table and table schema across our databases.

I want it to look something like this:

| table_schema | table_name | column_name | maximum_batch_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Schema_1_Name | Table_Name_1 | batch_id | 1252753 |
| Schema_1_Name | Table_Name_2 | batch_id | 1252753 |
| Schema_2_Name | Table_Name_1 | batch_id | 1252757 |

I can get the information_schema information for table_schema, table_name and column_name using:

`select table_schema, table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'batch_id'`

I could not figure out a way to get the batch_id value without a lot of unions.  If there is a better way, please let me know.

How do I get the table_schema, table_name and column_name to be included with my results?  Do I have to hard code them or is there an easier way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I could not figure out a way to get the batch_id value without a lot of unions. If there is a better way, please let me know.* Noway. Moreover, the iteration over your rowset with dynamic Sql usage needed. PS. `DISTINCT` is obviously excess in your query.